# What is the module.directive function parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've seen directives with a lot of different function parameters. So far I've see things like :

Empty function:

```
.directive('myDialog', function() { /* ... */ });
```

An array :

```
.directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) { /* ... */ });
```

And some more :

```
.directive('tetris', function ($timeout) { /* ... */ });
.directive('mypopover', function ($compile,$templateCache) { /* ... */ });
.directive("myDirective", function($document) { /* ... */ });
```

I know this is just different variable names, but it seems to be used for different behaviors.
How does the directive function works?

Comment: Directives should be used for DOM manipulation, plain and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't just for directives, but this is the syntax with how [AngularJS handles dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).  You can injection whatever dependencies you like to the callback function, in any order, that you want to use in the component.  Above you have posted two different versions of the syntax -- one with the array and one without.

```
.directive("tetris", function ($timeout) {
```

This will automatically *inject* the `$timeout` service to this directive so it can be used in the directive's definition and functions.

```
.directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
```

This is a different way of writing the syntax so that you could call the `$document` variable whatever you wanted -- useful for minification.

Dependency Injection is a killer feature of AngularJS and it is very important to learn and understand it.